# Send response to server with device actual geolocation on receiving FCM push notification

Tags: android, service, location, push

We are developing an android app that is supposed to do the following:

1. User installs the app, registers and closes the app (app in background or killed).
2. When web-server wants to find out user current location it sends him a push notification.
3. When notification received, a foreground service is started to acquire a GPS-provided location.
4. The acquired location is sent to a web-service.
5. Foreground service stops.

We use push notifications, so that location is sent to server only when it's needed.
We want to use a foreground service to bypass Background Location Limits.

Is our plan correct?

Comment: What about runtime permissions?

Comment: @Bek, thank you for reminding. We will consider that users are interested in app correct behaviour.